# How to use webhook in gitlab using php?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to use the gitlab webhook on commit event. Actually i want to save the commit comment on my own database. so i need to run a file that save the commit comment and also project id.

Please let me know how can i do it?

Comment: The web hook calls you php script. In the payload you will find your commit which you can save to your database.